StateProvider not updating child widgets
I'm using Riverpod to manage a CharacterCreationState which holds values for user selections from the UI, the current step the user is on for character creation, and JSON called from a GraphQL API which holds a list of options the user selects from to add information to their character.
The CharacterCreationState:
class CharacterCreationState {
  int currentStep;
  DndRace dndRace;
  AsyncValue<List<Item>> currentItems;

  CharacterCreationState(
      {this.currentStep = 0,
      required this.dndRace,
      AsyncValue<List<Item>>? currentItems})
      : currentItems = currentItems ?? const AsyncValue.data([]);

  CharacterCreationState copyWith(
      {int? currentStep,
      DndRace? dndRace,
      AsyncValue<List<Item>>? currentItems}) {
    return CharacterCreationState(
        currentStep: currentStep ?? this.currentStep,
        dndRace: dndRace ?? this.dndRace,
        currentItems: currentItems ?? this.currentItems);
  }
}

The function in my ViewModel that updates the CharacterCreationState:
Future<void> getRaceAbilityBonusOptions(String raceName) async {
    state = state.copyWith(currentItems: const AsyncValue.loading());
    try {
      final AbilityBonusChoice abilityBonusChoices =
          await raceRepository.getRaceAbilityBonusChoice(raceName);
      state = state.copyWith(
          currentItems: AsyncValue.data(abilityBonusChoices.toItemList()));
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
      print(StackTrace.current);
      state =
          state.copyWith(currentItems: AsyncValue.error(e, StackTrace.current));
    }
  }
}

The widget that controls the step:
class ButtonProgressionView extends StatelessWidget {
  final int currentStep;
  final VoidCallback goBack;
  final VoidCallback goForward;
  const ButtonProgressionView({
    required this.goBack,
    required this.goForward,
    required this.currentStep,
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Expanded(
        flex: 3,
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Row(
            children: [
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                onPressed: currentStep == 0 ? null : () => goBack(),
                child: const Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [Icon(Icons.arrow_back), Text("Go Back")],
                ),
              ),
              const Spacer(),
              ElevatedButton(
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.blue),
                onPressed: currentStep == 1 ? null : () => goForward(),
                child: const Row(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [Text("Go Next"), Icon(Icons.arrow_forward)],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}

The widget that contains which Widget to show depending on the currentStep:
class CurrentStepSelectionView extends StatelessWidget {
  final CharacterCreationState currentState;
  final CreateCharacterViewModel viewModel;
  final void Function(int) addCurrentOptionSelection;

  const CurrentStepSelectionView(
      {super.key,
      required this.currentState,
      required this.addCurrentOptionSelection,
      required this.viewModel});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return currentState.currentItems.when(
        data: (response) {
          return Expanded(
              flex: 9,
              child: switch (currentState.currentStep) {
                0 => ChooseRaceView(
                    chooseRaceAndProceed: addCurrentOptionSelection,
                    items: response),
                1 => ChooseAbilityBonuses(
                    chooseBonusesAndProceed: addCurrentOptionSelection,
                    items: response),
                _ => Container()
              });
        },
        error: (error, stackTrace) =>
            Center(child: Text("error: $error, $stackTrace")),
        loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
  }
}

And the widget in question that is not updating when a selection is made and the currentStep gets updated:
class ChooseRaceView extends StatelessWidget {
  final void Function(int) chooseRaceAndProceed;
  final List<Item> items;
  const ChooseRaceView(
      {super.key, required this.chooseRaceAndProceed, required this.items});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CarouselView(
        itemExtent: 250,
        itemSnapping: true,
        elevation: 4,
        onTap: chooseRaceAndProceed,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
        children: List.generate(items.length, (int index) {
          return Container(
            color: Colors.grey,
            child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    flex: 7,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/images/${items[index].index}_icon.png",
                        fit: BoxFit.contain,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
                    child: Text(items[index].name,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headlineLarge),
                  )
                ]),
          );
        }));
  }
}

When I click on the "Go Next" button, the next CarouselView does not update with the updated CharacterCreationState.currentItems. Instead, it shows a +0 and the PREVIOUS state's currentItems names 
I have debugged this to high heaven and the state does change and gets updated eventually. But it never changes the information on the Carousels.
I may just need a hard lesson in state management or maybe CarouselView isn't built for something like this, but can anyone at least give any direction as to why this isn't working?
I've tried modifying the key to CarouselView, I've tried moving the widgets directly into the parent widget, I've tried forcing the CreateCharacterState to notify the listeners. I'm out of ideas at this point.

I would recommend creating a minimal reproducible example, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. You could start by mocking the onTap: chooseRaceAndProceed callback to test if, in principle, your widget does what it should, and work your way backwards from there.

Avoid legacy riverpod tools. In brief, avoid legacy ChangeNotifier, StateNotifier (and their providers) and StateProvider.  Use only Provider, FutureProvider, StreamProvider, and Notifier, AsyncNotifier, StreamNotifier (and their providers).
